# Jquery: How to make Slider working After Ajax call?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-slider

**Hello!**

i have a very nice Filter plugin i made with Jquery UI Slider, Here is the Full code And working Example:

http://jsbin.com/epikam/1/edit

Its working great, The Only problem is That After Ajax call it does not Change the Items..

**Here is the Ajax call:**

```
$.ajax({
     url: "search.php",
     dataType: 'json',
     type: 'GET',
     data: "q="+value+"&category="+cat+"&country="+country+"&page="+page,
         success: function(data){
            globalRequest = 0;
            resultContainer.fadeOut('fast', function() {
    resultContainer.html('');
        for (var x in data) {                   
    var html = '<li class="item" data-type="league2" data-id="id-'+x+'" style="position: relative;">';
    html += '<label class="title"><a href="'+data[x].url+'" target="_blank">'+data[x].Title+'</a></label>';
    html += '<img src="'+data[x].img+'">';
    html += '<label class="price">New Price: '+data[x].newprice+'</label>';
        html += '</li>';

        resultContainer.append(html);
        }

    resultContainer.fadeIn('fast');
            });
              }
            });
```

I tried to Use .live and .delegate With no success (Im not sure how\where to use it)

**Any suggestions??**

Thank you very much!!!

Eran.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First, check that the success function is being called with something like `console.log(data);` in the `success:` callback and that there are not errors stopping the Ajax call from completing successfully. In the JavaScript console, check that the variable `data` has been correctly populated and contains the data you expect it to contain.

Secondly, use JQuery selectors instead of global variables within the ajax success call. E.g. use `$("#resultContainer")` (assuming the div has an id `resultContainer`) instead of the variable resultContainer.